# Different results than the ones I am searching for

Tags: c++

I'm writing this c++ console program that has to search a bunch of people by name in a binary file and display all data for the record found. The problem is that when I search for a name that's for example third or fourth the program always shows me the first one.

You can see the problem on those pictures too:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HIss.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7V0I.png]

```
void search_by_name()
{
    {
        depositor p_Info;
        char name[50];
        data_file.open("info.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
        if (!data_file)
        {
            cout << "Error while opening file!";
            exit(1);
        }
        data_file.seekg(0 * sizeof(struct depositor), ios::beg);
        data_file.read((char*)(&p_Info), sizeof(depositor));
        cout << "\n\n* Please enter a name you would like to search: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(2000, '\n');
        cin.getline(name, 50);
        while (p_Info.full_name == name)
            cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "/=====================================================/" << endl;
        cout << "/=========  Number: " << p_Info.numb << endl;
        cout << "/=========  Full name: " << p_Info.full_name << endl;
        cout << "/=========  Address: " << p_Info.address << endl;
        cout << "/=====================================================/" << endl;
        data_file.close();
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: `0 * sizeof(struct depositor)` is always `0`, so `p_Info` will always contain the first `depositor` record. What else were you expecting?

Comment: Please post `depositor`.  Depending on what it is, this whole approach may be invalid.

Comment: You really should stop posting for a while and use the debugger.  You'll learn a lot and catch a lot of defects in your program.

Comment: Your while loop will either not find anything or will loop infinitely, since you never change either of the variables within the loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You can see the depositor struct and all functions here http://prntscr.com/5qxo2k

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I deleted the last post because I asked the wrong question.

Comment: Debugger, debugger, debugger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 p_Info.full_name == name
```

It's not the right way to compare to strings in C++.
Use `strcmp(p_Info.full_name, name) == 0`, for example, or use `std::string`.
Oh, yes, and also, I suppose, you want to put this line in while loop as well as in where it's now:

```
data_file.read((char*)(&p_Info), sizeof(depositor));
```

The while loop should look like this:

```
//while we didn't find the right one, continue reading
while(strcmp(p_Info.full_name, name) != 0)
    data_file.read((char*)(&p_Info), sizeof(depositor));
```

Comment: To avoid this pitfall, `std::string` can be used.

Comment: I agree, whenever is possible, but I suppose in this situation it's easier to use strcmp.

Comment: But you should also consider situation where there is no such name in file, and you reach end of file (eof()) without success.

Comment: You should also include check for End of File. When there is no p_Info with requested name in file error will happen, so you must prevent that. And as many people here suggested learn how to use debugger (inside your IDE). Then go step by step and see how your program works.

Answer (score 0):

The function only reads the first record (from the 0th byte of the file to `sizeof(depositor)`) but it never reads the file after the line where the depositor's name is read from `cin`, therefore it cannot possibly obtain any data from the file other than the first record.

Comment: How should I change the algorythm so I can get the result I'm searching for?

Comment: You could start by considering Barmar's comment then try stepping through the code with the debugger, as Thomas Matthews wisely suggests. Ask yourself "What am I trying to achieve with each line?" and, as you step through the code, ask yourself if the line is actually doing what you want.